# What's an efficient way to delete threaded comments from database in active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, tree

In our app we have user Posts, and comments on user posts. Users can comment on comments as well, so it's kind of like the Reddit Post model. Because of product requirements, when a user deletes their post, all comments, including comment replies have to be deleted as well. We run into situations where the comment thread count could go into the thousands. I was wondering what the best way would be to handle this in Rails/Active Record? I was thinking of doing like a depth first search and batch deleting comments. I saw some available gems for mapping db records into tree like structures, but they all require adding a db column which I want to avoid. Does anyone have any suggestions? We are using Postgres 10 and rails 5

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to do it in ActiveJob and perform comments deletion in background.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord has `after_destroy` callback, it would be useful to use with background workers.

Also, not suggesting to use `:dependent => :destroy`, in your cases it will be wrong.

```
  after_destroy :delete_comments

  private
  def delete_comments
      BlablaDeleteCommentsJob.perform_later(self.id)
  end
```

```
# worker | job
class BlablaDeleteCommentsJob < ApplicationJob

    def perform(blog_id)
        puts "*"*50
        puts "Performing from |BlablaDeleteComments Job| "
        puts "*"*50

        # batch delete comments here
        Comment.where(blog_id: blog_id).delete_all
    end
end
```